# How to check if a Form has focus?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have two `WinForm`s. Let's say `MainForm` and `ChildForm`.

What I'm trying to make is when the `MainForm` is activated the `ChildForm` should always be visible, and when the `MainForm` loses focus the `ChildForm` should be hidden except if it's the `ChildForm` which was activated.

Here is my code :

```
AddHandler Me.MainForm.Activated, Sub()        
                                      Me.ChildForm.Show()                                              
                                  End Sub

AddHandler Me.MainForm.Deactivate, Sub()                                               
                                       If Not Me.ChildForm.Focused Then                                                   
                                           Me.ChildForm.Hide()
                                       End If
                                   End Sub

AddHandler Me.ChildForm.Deactivate, Sub()
                                        If Not MainForm.Focused Then
                                            Me.ChildForm.Hide()
                                        End If
                                    End Sub
```

The code doesn't work. Basically when I click on a certain form (on the child form for example), the property Me.ChildForm.Focused is not correct and then `ChildForm` is hidden while it should be visible.

Can anyone know how to achieve that please ?

Comment: You have two winforms, Me.MainForm, and Me.ChildForm. Then what is Me?

Comment: A form almost never has the focus, it is one of the controls inside the form that gets it.  Like a button or textbox.  So the code as posted is doomed to not work.  Not the only problem, activating the "child" form will de-activate the main form and that hides the child.  What is quite unclear is what *other* window needs to be activated to get the child to hide.  It is not obvious from the question.

Comment: @djv Me refers to a wrapper class that handles the logic expected. It's not that important

Comment: @Hans Passant, the logic I'm trying to implement is when the child form is activated, indeed the main form will be deactivated, there will be a check whether the child form is activated or not. If the child form is activated, nothing should change. Otherwise (that means that something else has been activated) hide the child form. Do you know another way to achieve that please ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is a good one, but the idea is using flags for MainForm and ChildForm active status. These flags are set when MainForm and ChildForm's Activated and Deactive events are fired. For simplicity, I'll use a module to store the flags and the instance of ChildForm. Then call SetChildVisible() method in MainForm, Form1 and Form2 Activated event. Set startup object to MainForm.

**Module1**

```
Module Module1

    Public FChild As ChildForm

    Public FMainActive As Boolean
    Public FChildActive As Boolean

    Public Sub SetChildVisible()
        FChild.Visible = Not FChildActive And FMainActive
    End Sub

End Module
```

**MainForm**

```
Public Class MainForm

    Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim f1 = New Form1
        Dim f2 = New Form2
        Dim child = New ChildForm

        Module1.FChild = child

        child.Show()
        f1.Show()
        f2.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub MainForm_Activated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Activated
        Module1.FMainActive = True
        Module1.SetChildVisible()
    End Sub

    Private Sub MainForm_Deactivate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Deactivate
        Module1.FMainActive = False
    End Sub

End Class
```

**ChildForm**

```
Public Class ChildForm

    Private Sub ChildForm_Activated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Activated
        Module1.FChildActive = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub ChildForm_Deactivate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Deactivate
        Module1.FChildActive = False
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Form1**

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Activated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Activated
        Module1.SetChildVisible()
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Form2**

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub Form2_Activated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Activated
        Module1.SetChildVisible()
    End Sub

End Class
```